# How can I change a phone's language using Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I change the language of a phone using Kotlin?
[image: An example of what I want to change]

This is a picture showing the thing that I want to change through the code. Can it be done through the code or not?

Comment: I would hope that this is impossible.  I wouldn't want an app to be able to change my phone language, only the settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to do it programmatically. The best you can do is to open Locale Settings screen like this:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS), 0);
```